# Right click menu turns black

Tags: windows-7, right-click, logmein, hamachi

I've installed LogMeIn Hamachi in order to host certain game servers without having to port forward, and it has caused a really annoying problem. Sometimes, after Hamachi has been launched, when I right click this happens:

[image: It turns black like this]

If I mouse-over the options, they turn somewhat visible, but I have to mouse over every single one of them, like this

[image: I have to mouse over every single one]

A restart fixes this, but it happens quite often, so I don't wanna restart all the time.  Hope you guys can help :)

Comment: Have you tried updating your video drivers to the latest version offered by the manufacturer?

Comment: Yes I have - all drivers are up to date :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the Transition Effects for Menus and Tooltips

Follow these steps:

1. Start
2. Right Click Computer
3. Select Properties
4. Click the Advanced System Settings
5. Advanced Tab
6. Under Performance, Click Settings
7. Under Custom: Uncheck the check-box FADE OR SLIDE MENUS INTO VIEW
8. Apply & OK.